# Executing find command for geting all the files modified after a date

Tags: php, exec

I have used shell `find` command for listing all the files in a directory.It is working fine.I want to list all the files that are modified after a specified date i have used this command

```
$command='touch -date "2010-01-18" /home;find.-newer /home ';
$Getfile = exec($command,$ret,$output);
```

But it is not working .Thanks in advance

Comment: What is not working, the shell command or the `exec()` call? What do you get? An error, no output etc...

Comment: I bet if you use *that* find command within shell, it won't work as well.

Comment: the -newer argument needs a pointer to a file as reference for which files it should display as newer. see man page `File  was  modified more recently than file.  If file is a symbolic link and the -H option or the -L option is in effect, the modification time of the file it points to is always used.` So you would have to touch a file not a directory, and use this file as reference, or you just spare the touch and use `-cmin <minutes since last change>` as you use php its a pity to calc the minutes for a specific date.

Comment: @DaveRandom I am getting all the files in this folder

Comment: You would get more granular control over this, not risk breaking your script if/when you port it to Windows or some other OS, and not have to parse the output of another command if you use a combination of `opendir()` and `filemtime()` to do this job...

Answer (score 0):

Find all files modified after specific date in current directory

```
$command='touch -t 201001180000 /tmp/timestamp; find . -type f -newer /tmp/timestamp'
```

Comment: Can i specify another directory?

Comment: absolutely, 
$command='touch -t 201001180000 $path1; find $path2 -type f -newer $path1'

Answer (score 0):

You can use directory for find, however, the suggested syntax is --

```
find ABSOLUTE_PATH -newer /home -type f
```

`.` is current working directory,
(in web environment could be refer to DOCUMENT_ROOT + REQUEST_URI)